# How to add listbox items with specific text color?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to add a list of computers to a listbox from a text file, and based off whether or not a ping succeeds on the computer it should color it green for success or red for failure. The problem is that it uses the last color from the last computer on all items. I believe this is because Drawitem event isnt raised until after the for loop has completed, but I can't think of a way around this. Any help is appreciated. (reduced code for ping)

```
    private logitem linez;

    struct logitem
    {
        public string text;
        public Brush color;
    };
private void browsebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
string textfile = ofd.FileName;
            if (textfile != "")
            {
                string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@textfile);
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    if (line != "")
                    {
                        string liner;
                        liner = line.Replace(" ", "");
                        if (ping successfull)
                        {
                        listBoxAddGreen();
                        }
                        else (ping fails)
                        {
                         listBoxAddRed();
                         }
                    }
                    changeCount();

                }
}
       public void listBoxAddGreen ()
    {
        linez.color = Brushes.Green;
        listBox1.Items.Add(linez.text);
    }
                  public void listBoxAddRed ()
    {
        linez.color = Brushes.Red;
        listBox1.Items.Add(linez.text);
    }

        private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender,
System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        Brush myBrush = linez.color;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
            e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

Comment: Are you open to using a `ListView`? It's easier to work with for changing the color.

Comment: Do you have draw mode set to `OwnerDrawnFixed`?

Comment: You **must** get familiar with MVVM. Using it your task will be solved for couple of minutes. 1) do ping in view-model; 2) every pinged item should has its view-model (for example, `ItemVM`) with `PingOk` property showing whether ping was succesfull or not; 3) bind `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` to collection of `ItemVM`; 4) set trigger in XAML for `ListBoxItem` changing `Foreground` depending on value of the `PingOk` property. And `ListBox` is much more useful for your task than `ListView` so stick with this items control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played around with it a little, and discovered how we can do the same thing with a `ListBox`. The trick is to add an item that stores both the color and the text. You were doing that with a struct, I am using a class:

```
class ColoredItem
{
    public string Text;
    public Color Color;
};
```

Now, we can create the colored item in much the same was as in my other answer, where we ping the server and set the color to `Green` if the ping was successful, otherwise set it to `Red`. And we set the `Text` property to the `server` name. Note that we just call `listBox1.Add(item)` directly now, since we are relying on our custom draw method to change the color:

```
public static bool PingServer(string serverName)
{
    try { return new Ping().Send(serverName)?.Status == IPStatus.Success; }
    catch { return false; }
}

private void browsebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var serversFile = @"f:\public\temp\servers.txt";

    var servers = File.ReadAllLines(serversFile)
        .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
        .Select(l => l.Replace(" ", ""));

    foreach (var server in servers)
    {
        var color = PingServer(server)
            ? Color.Green
            : Color.Red;

        ColoredItem coloredItem = new ColoredItem {Color = color, Text = server};

        listBox.Items.Add(coloredItem);
    }
}
```

Now, in our `DrawItem` method, we try to cast the item to an instance of our `ColoredItem` class. Note that the `DrawItemEventArgs` contains the `Index` of the item we're adding. When we call the `DrawString` method, we can now use our `item.Text` for the server name, and `item.Color` for the brush color:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var item = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as ColoredItem;

    if (item != null)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(
            item.Text, 
            e.Font, 
            new SolidBrush(item.Color), 
            e.Bounds);
    }
}
```

The only other thing we need to ensure is that the `DrawMode` for the `ListBox` is set to `OwnerDrawFixed`, so our custom draw code gets called:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
}
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Comment: Worked great, I think the main issue was in my DrawItem method, which was fixed by casting to the ColoredItem Class.  Also, the way you wrote the code was much simpler and more eloquent. The only thing I have to figure out now is how to get the results to show quicker. (It waits until all items are ping'd before drawing)

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a `ListView` control, it's pretty easy. First, set the view to `List`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.List;
}
```

Then, you can create a generic function that will add a colored item to a `ListView`. Basically all this does is add the item first, then use it's index (which will be the last one, or `Count - 1`) to change the forecolor:

```
private static void AddColoredItemToListView(ListView listView, string item, Color color)
{
    listView.Items.Add(item);
    listView.Items[listView.Items.Count - 1].ForeColor = color;
}
```

Since you didn't include a `Ping` method, I'll include a simple one here:

```
public static bool PingServer(string serverName)
{
    try { return new Ping().Send(serverName)?.Status == IPStatus.Success; }
    catch { return false; }
}
```

Now, to call the method, all we do is read our servers file, and ping each server. If the call to `PingServer` returns true, we set a color variable to `Green`, otherwise we set it to `Red`, and then we call the method we created above:

```
private void browsebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var serversFile = @"f:\public\temp\servers.txt";

    var servers = File.ReadAllLines(serversFile)
        .Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l))
        .Select(l => l.Replace(" ", ""));

    foreach (var server in servers)
    {
        var color = PingServer(server)
            ? Color.Green
            : Color.Red;

        AddColoredItemToListView(listView1, server, color);
    }
}
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Or, if you prefer, you could change the `BackColor` instead:

[image]