# ListBox change the element's text color by condition

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

How you can change the text color of a line if, for example, the word "Error" appears in it, I can imagine how to make a check, but there is no way to change the color of one element. I would be grateful for your help!

```
private void LoadFTP()
{
    listBox2.Items.Clear();
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ServerIP/Logs/"+path);
    reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Login", "Password");
    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    reqFTP.Proxy = GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(line);
            listBox2.TopIndex = listBox2.Items.Count - 1;
        }
        // Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", responseString); 
        stream.Close();
    }
    response.Close(); //Closes the connection to the server
}
```

P.S. I don't understand English well, but you have a more adequate community than the Russian one.

Comment: If this is WinForms, you would have to look at the DrawMode property and the DrawItem event.

Comment: @LarsTech, I tried to do it according to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45069356/4796672. But I had a problem that when clicking on an element, the text is distorted, when scrolling it is the same. In my case now, I have disabled the selection of elements.

Comment: Another example: [ListBox.DrawItem Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem?view=net-5.0). Note that it also draws the background and the selection rectangle to display selected items correctly.

Comment: You would have to show us *your code* if you have a question about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use ListView instead ListBox

```
private void FillListView()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i == 9)
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem($"number {i}") {ForeColor = Color.Green });
        else
            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem($"number {i}"));
    }
}
```

But if you need exactly ListBox i think you can do it only through Draw_Item event.